# Moviepy doubles the speed of the video without affecting audio. I suspect a framerate issue but I havent been able to fix it

Tags: python, moviepy

Right now here is all I'm having moviepy do:

```
full_video = VideoFileClip(input_video_path)
full_video.write_videofile("output.mp4")
quit()
```

It just takes the video and writes it to another file with no changes. But when the input video looks like [this](https://youtu.be/QpAtGf4yABw) the output ends up looking like [this](https://youtu.be/De8LVwxkbNE) with the video speed doubled but the audio just the same. I could take the audio and video separately, halve the speed of the video then put them back together but is there a way I can correct for whatever problem is causing this?

edit 2: It is the VideoFileClip method causing the speedup most likely, not the write_videofile method. When I try

```
full_video = VideoFileClip(input_video_path)
print( full_video.fps )
full_video.preview(fps = full_video.fps)
quit()
```

it is still double speed in the preview.

edit 3: The problem only happens with videos captured with Windows game bar. I tried a different video and it worked just fine with no speedup. I'll probably just find a different way to capture the screen recordings to fix it but I dont know what the root problem was

edit 1: the full code

```
from moviepy.editor import *

# get all dash times
times_path = "times.txt"
input_video_path = "input.mp4"



offset_time = 0
clip_length = float( input("Enter clip length: ") )

def get_times(path, offset):
    dash_times_str = []
    with open(path, "r") as file:
        dash_times_str = file.readlines()

    count = 0
    # Strips the newline character
    # also add offset time
    temp = []
    for line in dash_times_str:
        count += 1
        temp.append ("{}".format(line.strip()))
    dash_times_str = temp
    dash_times = []
    for time in dash_times_str:
        dash_times.append( float(time) + offset )
    return dash_times

dash_times = get_times(times_path, offset_time)

def get_offset_time():
    a = float(input("Enter time for first dash in video"))
    b = dash_times[0]
    return a-b
offset_time = get_offset_time()

full_video = VideoFileClip(input_video_path)


counter = 0
times_count = len(dash_times)
clips = []
for dash_time in dash_times:
    clip = full_video.subclip(dash_time,dash_time+clip_length)
    clips.append(clip)
    counter+=1
    print("Clip " + str(counter) + " out of " + str(times_count))

final_clip = concatenate_videoclips(clips)
final_clip.write_videofile("output.mp4")
```

Comment: Sharing the full code would make it easier for others to help :)

Comment: @Meh I added the full code of the project but most of it doesn't do anything when I just output the video file with no edits. I also deterined that it isnt the write_videofile method that's causing the speedup, I'm pretty sure it is the VideoFileClip method which is the problem

Answer (score 1):

I haven't been able to go deep down in the source code to figure out why this is, but I could indeed duplicate your bug with videos recorded with the Windows game bar.

I also agree with you that it seems to be tied directly to the VideoFileClip method.

I got my code to work by writing it like this:

```
full_video = VideoFileClip(input_video_path, fps_source="fps")
```

with the key detail being the (fps_source = "fps") bit.